# Retrieve Loop textbox

Tags: php

page_form.php

```
echo '<div style="text-align:center;margin-left:25px;">
          <form action="grad.php" method="post">               
            <table width-"100%">
                  <tr><th style="padding:12px;">LETTER </th>
                      <th style="padding:12px;">INTERVAL</th>
                      <th style="padding:12px;">GT</th>
                  </tr>';
                 for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
                  {
                   echo '<tr><td style="padding:12px;"><input type="text" name="letter_'.$i.'"></td>
                             <td style="padding:12px;"><input type="text" name="interval'.$i.'"></td>
                             <td style="padding:12px;"><input type="text" name="gt'.$i.'"></td>
                         </tr>';
                  }
                  echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>';
           echo '</table>
         </form>
        </div>';
```

grad.php

```
$letter = $_POST['letter']; 
     $interval = $_POST['interval']; 
     $gt = $_POST['gt']; 
$s = mysql_query("INSERT INTO grad_table(letter,markint,gradepoint) VALUES('$letter',$interval,$gt) ");
```

I have given all the textboxes in a forloop. when I click on submit I need to get all the 5 textbox values, but right now iam getting only the 1st row.

Database Structure

```
   Field   Type          Collation      Attributes     Extra
     id    bigint(10)                    UNSIGNED     AUTO_INCREMENT
   letter  varchar(255)  utf+general_ci  
   markint  bigint(10)
     gt     bigint(10)
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textbox names are not `letter`, as you're using them - they are `letter_0`, `letter_1`, etc.

Also, `interval` is a [MySQL reserved-word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and you'll need to escape it using backticks: `` `interval` ``.

To retrieve all of them, you can hardcode all of their names such as `$letter1 = $_POST['letter_1'];`, or you can do it in another loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $letter = $_POST['letter_' . $i]; 
    $interval = $_POST['interval' . $i]; 
    $gt = $_POST['gt' . $i]; 
    $s = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `grad_table` (`letter`, `interval`, `gt`) VALUES ('$letter',$interval,$gt)");
}
```

One big thing to note here is that you should really validate your user-input before inserting it into the database. First, you can use `isset()` before accessing the variables to make sure the user submitted the data. Second, you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to sanitize the string input and `intval()` for the integers:

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    // check that each field is posted
    if (!isset($_POST['letter_' . $i]) || !isset($_POST['interval' . $i]) || !isset($_POST['gt' . $i])) continue;

    // assign & sanitize
    $letter = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['letter_' . $i]); 
    $interval = intval($_POST['interval' . $i]); 
    $gt = intval($_POST['gt' . $i]); 
    $s = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `grad_table` (`letter`, `interval`, `gt`) VALUES ('$letter',$interval,$gt) ");
}
```

Now, this doesn't "validate" your data, but at least it will help prevent SQL injection and simply PHP errors.

Comment: Thank You, I will surely make isset in my file

Comment: the code was working fine and iam able to echo all the values, but not inserting to the database

Comment: newfurniturey@The code in your answer was working fine, but not able to insert to database [talking about your answer code]

Comment: @thersa Ah - I missed this the first time around. [`interval`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is a MySQL reserved word and needs to be escaped using backticks. I've updated my answer with all table/column names escaped.

Comment: I have replaced interval as inter in my two files, but even Iam able to echo them but not inserting to table

Comment: Yes I have renamed the column too

Comment: a
43543
435
Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'b    
4543
547
Unknown column 'b' in 'field list'c
5435
454
Unknown column 'c' in 'field list'd
47
543
Unknown column 'd' in 'field list'e
454
354
Unknown column 'e' in 'field list'f
454
545
Unknown column 'f' in 'field list'g
43
57
Unknown column 'g' in 'field list' ----- Thi sis the error Iam getting when I echo mysql_error();

Comment: @thersa I'm assuming then that the values for your column `gt` (or `interval` even) are not numeric? If they're strings, you have to wrap them in quotes in your query - like `letter` is wrapped in my example above.

Comment: newfurniturey@I have given my database structure above. I think everything is going well

Comment: newfurniturey@Is my database structure fine

Comment: newfurniturey@the problem was solved and I thank You for your answers. since Iam giving letter column varchar datatype, i need to show in "" while writing insert statememnt

Answer (score 0):

Your post data should containt `$_POST['interval0']`, `$_POST['interval1']`, `$_POST['interval2']`...

You will have to trawl through each `$_POST` to get all the answers. I an frankly surprised you are getting *any* post data with your code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

you should modify following

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
{
  echo '<tr><td style="padding:12px;"><input type="text" name="letter['.$i.']"></td>
  <td style="padding:12px;"><input type="text" name="interval['.$i.']"></td>
  <td style="padding:12px;"><input type="text" name="gt['.$i.']"></td>
  </tr>';
}
```

then you can do following

```
foreach($_POST['letter'] as $i=>$v) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO grad_table(letter,interval,gt) VALUES('{$_POST['letter'][$i]}',{$_POST['interval'][$i]},{$_POST['gt'][$i]}) ");
}
```

Comment: It was inserting only the last one, but not all